# Lebesgue integral of vector-valued function?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Bernt Øksendals stochastic differential equations he says that if we have a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$. He defines the expectation:

$E[X]=\int_\Omega X(\omega)dP(\Omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}xd\mu_X(x)$.

But what is the definition of an integral over a vector-valued function? I've tried to find it in various measure theory books, but the most I could find is integration of complex valued function. How is this integral defined, have you any references for measure or probability books, where this is defined? It seems likely that we integrate componentwise in some way, but I'd like to see some rigorous way of defining this integral so that we know everything works.

Comment: Yes, for $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued functions, it's just componentwise integration.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you very much, but can I please ask you then about another thing, I asked a related question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643097/getting-conditional-expectation-using-the-radon-nikodym-derivative-for-multidime and if it is defined componentwise, how can then wikipedia define $\int_\Omega X dP $ as a measure, are there measures that have many components?

Comment: One can define vector-valued measures. But as long as we're only looking at $\mathbb{R}^d$, such a thing is just a $d$-tuple of ordinary real measures.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the componentwise integration. Here I'd try to provide some justification for this matter.

Suppose a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.
First, we have a random vector $\mathbf{X}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$, which is a measurable vector-valued function with respect to the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and a measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B})$ with $\mathcal{B}$ being a Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Here I express the random vector with the boldface instead of the standard font to emphasize that it is a vector-valued function. We may decompose $\mathbf{X}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ into
\begin{equation}
    \forall \omega \in \Omega:\;
    \mathbf{X}(\omega) = (X_1(\omega), \dotsc, X_d(\omega))
\end{equation}
where $X_1, \dotsc, X_d: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable functions with respect to $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and a measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \tilde{\mathcal{B}})$. Now supposing $\mathcal{S} := (\mathbf{e}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{e}_d)$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^d$, then we can express
\begin{equation}
    \forall \omega \in \Omega:\;
    \mathbf{X}(\omega) = \sum_{k = 1}^d \mathbf{e}_k X_k(\omega) \,.
\end{equation}
Before proceeding, we may also asserts that at least $X_1, \dotsc, X_d \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.
By definition, we have
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{E}[\mathbf{X}] := \int_\Omega \mathbf{X} \,\mathrm{d}P \,.
\end{equation}
And by applying the basic property of Lebesgue integral, we obtain
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{E}[\mathbf{X}]
    = \int_\Omega \mathbf{X} \,\mathrm{d}P
    = \int_\Omega \sum_{k = 1}^d \mathbf{e}_k X_k \, \mathrm{d}P
    = \sum_{k = 1}^d \mathbf{e}_k \int_\Omega X_k \, \mathrm{d}P
    = \sum_{k = 1}^d \mathbf{e}_k \mathrm{E}[X_k]
\end{equation}
which is a componentwise integration. Thus, the expected value of random variable $\mathbf{X}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is some point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$. We may justify the expression above by treating the sum as the sum of vectors, which distributes over scalars, and the integrands are scalars. And that the integral also distributes over the sum is the basic property of Lebesgue integration on Lebesgue integrable functions (i. e., $\mathcal{L}^1$ or $\mathcal{L}^p$ in general).

This matter currently coincides with a practical topic that I'm currently working on, about the centre of gravity of piles with respect to the horizontal plane. A civil engineering problem though. I am currently developing an algorithm in Python for computing the piles reaction to the forces transmitted into them, and it involves finding the centre of gravity of these piles. I'd like to make the problem more abstract by incorporating measure theory and probability theory, in a hope that, this algorithm can solve any kind of irregular pile configurations. I model the centres of piles as point vectors in 3D Euclidean space. And the centre of gravity of these piles is given by the expected value of the points vectors, which is a point vector. In a more rigorous way, these point vectors are the image of a random vector
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{p}: [N] &\to V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 \\
    k &\mapsto \mathbf{p}_k \,,
\end{align}
by supposing there are $N$ piles in the corresponding pile group, for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and also $[N] := \{1, \dotsc, N\}$. And the underlying probability space is $([N], \mathcal{P}([N]), P)$ with $P: \mathcal{P}([N]) \to [0, 1]$ being defined by
\begin{equation}
    \forall A \in \mathcal{P}([N]):\;
    P(A) := \frac{|A|}{N} \,.
\end{equation}
And the centre gravity of the piles is given by
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{p}_0
    := \int_{[N]} \mathbf{p} \,\mathrm{d}P
    = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 1}^N \mathbf{p}_k
    \,.
\end{equation}
I really am sorry if this last paragraph of my answer seems out of topic. I hope this answer can make this thing more sensible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

He is probably referring to the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral).

Edit: The Wikipedia page does a good job of presenting the definition. To answer your question in the comments, there is a natural theory of vector-valued measures, but when the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^d$ (and other finite products of measure spaces) these are just tuples $\mu = (\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_d)$ of measures $\mu_i$. Integration against $\mu$ is done component-wise.

Comment: So if you define a measure $\int_\Omega X dP$ and says that this is abs cont with respect to P, you mean that every component is abs cont with respect to P. And them you use the radon nikodym on each component measure? In your article it says that the Radon nikodym may not always hold, but it holds if you look componentwise? Is that what they have done under "formal definition, conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra " here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_.CF.83-algebra ?